# How to Add Character Minimums and Maximums for Wordpress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, character, contact-form

Using Wordpress Contact Form how can I add a character length limit and minimum? For example, how could I add a minimum length of 20 characters and a maximum length of 5,000 characters in the WPCF7 code below:

```
    [textarea* feedback-message id:feedback-message class:feedback-message "MESSAGE"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    [textarea* feedback-message id:feedback-message class:feedback-message minlength:20 maxlength:5000 "MESSAGE"]
```

When someone doesn't meet the character limits and minimum you set using the code it will give them an error message that is editable through the "Messages" tab.